# Haskell function example

Tags: haskell

Can someone give an example of a function with the following signature:

```
f :: a -> b -> (a -> b)
```

f takes two arguments, of type a and b, and returns a function which takes an argument of type a and returns an element of type b.

Our teacher gave us today this extra exercise and said it is really hard. I tried to write it using lambda expressions but I failed.

It is a really interesting exercise and, if someone figures out how to do it, please respond to this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, we can omit the parentheses, `a -> b -> (a -> b)` is the same as

```
a -> b -> a -> b
```

(This works because of [currying](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions))

Now look at this signature. We got the following inputs:

- two things of type `a`
- one thing of type `b`

We need to return something of type `b`. But now look, there is only one way to do this (if we ignore `undefined` for a moment), because we only got one value of type `b`! We just return that value:

```
f :: a -> b -> a -> b
f _ b _ = b -- We ignore both values of type a, because we cannot do anything with a's
```

---

So above I said that there is only just one solution if we ignore `undefined`, `error ...`, `let v = v in v` and similar (Those a called [bottom](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Bottom) values, because they either crash the program or won't terminate when evaluated). Can you find a definition that uses one of them?

---

**Edit**

As noted in the comments, this function actually has a *more general* type. I assumed that the exercise was to find a function which *can be* of that type, not a function whose inferred type is the given type. If that's not what you want, see [@bheklilr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22233533/2494803)

If you're interrested in short, but nigh unreadable definitions, see a similar question on [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20776/shortest-a-b-a-b-function-in-haskell)

Comment: Isn't `f _ b _ = b` of type `a -> b -> c -> b`

Comment: @hivert According to GHCi, yes.  This does not force the first and third parameters to have the same type.

Comment: arguably `undefined` is another answer if you allow for a more general type than the one you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry for spamming the comments but I have one more thing to mention. Bottom isn't the only type that will always work, `top` can as well (Typed Racket calls it `Any`) and it can actually evaluate to something: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type

Comment: @Wes: Sometimes, yes, but Haskell doesn't have subtyping, so there's neither a top *nor* a bottom type.  Every type in Haskell has a bottom *value*, but that's a different notion.  (I'm also not sure that you can use a top type for *this* function, but I'm not certain enough to claim that for sure.)

Answer (score 5):

A function of type `a -> b -> a -> b` could be represented as

```
f a1 b a2 = let xs = [a1, a2] in b
```

Since this forces `a1` and `a2` to have the same type in order to be in the same list.  The value of `xs` is just thrown away and we then return `b`.

---

Another would be

```
g a1 b a2 = let x = g a2 b a1 in b
```

Which doesn't use lists at all, but instead a pretty similar technique for tricking the compiler into unifying the types of `a1` and `a2`.

Comment: You could also write it as `g = (\_ b _ -> b) :: a -> b -> a -> b`, if I'm not missing something

Comment: @bennofs You have to provide it a type signature, I think the exercise is more about coming up with a function definition for which the compiler derives the signature `a -> b -> a -> b`.  Otherwise, I'd just slap the right type signature on `undefined` and call it a day.

Comment: What's the point of the `let` expressions? Just ignore the `a` arguments and return the `b`. The exercise is not to make an expression whose _inferred_ type is `a -> b -> a -> b`, that would be completely silly.

Comment: @pelotom The `let` expressions force the first and third arguments to have the same type, if you don't have that then the type would be `a -> b -> c -> b`

Comment: @bheklilr Any expression with the type `a -> b -> c -> b` also has the type `a -> b -> a -> b`. The point is to find an expression which _can be assigned_ the type `a -> b -> a -> b`, not one whose most-general type is `a -> b -> a -> b`.

Comment: @bheklilr At least that's what I would assume if I was given the problem. And obviously using `undefined` is just cheating.

Comment: @pelotom I assumed that the problem was to find a function whose signature is generalized as much as possible to `a -> b -> a -> b`, not one that specializes to that.  That's why I consider `f _ b _ = b` just as much of a cheat as `undefined`, it's more general of a type than `a -> b -> a -> b`.

Comment: @pelotom, if the exercise is to find a function whose principal type can be instantiated with the given type, then I would not consider `undefined` cheating because it can just as easily be instantiated with the right type. If you prefer you can just do `a :: a -> b -> (a -> b) ; a = a` which fits the parameters of the question and doesn't use `undefined` at all.

Comment: Also might as well note that djinn can find code that has a principal type that contains a type you give it (if the type is simple enough): https://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn

Comment: @Wes Under "cheating" I would file all bottoms, including non-terminating expressions like the one you gave. When a problem asks you to find a function of a certain type, I think it's safe to assume that you're being asked to pretend for a moment that Haskell is a total language and exhibit a _total_ function with that type

Comment: @pelotom, fair enough, it's not really worth arguing over, although imo the other interpretation is more interesting since the answer to this question can be computed easily though I'm not sure if principal type = given type can be calculated easily.

Comment: @Wes the fact that djinn can find the answer to this problem is just a sign that the problem is really easy :P

Comment: @Wes instantiating the principal type to some particular restriction is not hard at all, as evidenced by this answer

Answer (score 3):

```
f a' b a'' = const b (asTypeOf a' a'')
```

Answer (score 3):

There recently has been a question like this. Since there is no other requirement about what that returned value is, you can return the same `b` that was given, and ignore both values of type `a`. `b->a->b` is `const`. So `f _ = const` is the shortest function that will ignore the first and the third arguments, and return a value of the same type as the second argument. Yet, it doesn't bind the types of the first and the third arguments to be the same. We can do that by feeding both of them as the same argument to f.

One of the shortest ways to do that is through composition: `f _ = (.f).const` Now because the third argument is fed into `f` as the first argument, the types of these arguments will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
f a b c = const b (asTypeOf c a)      -- answer by md2perpe
        = const b (f c)
        = const b . f $ c
        = ((. f) . const) b c         -- answer by Sassa NF
```

this is a (*recursive*) definition, not an expression. So if you'd want to find an *expression* with this signature,

```
f  = const ((. f) . const) 
   = (const . (. const)) (. f)
   = ((const . (. const)) . flip (.)) f
   = fix ((const . (. const)) . flip (.))
```

`fix` is from `Data.Function`. `asTypeOf` is hardly a primitive combinator, as it is itself defined with the use of explicit type signatures, `asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a ; asTypeOf = const`. Use of `[]` was suggested:

```
f a b c = const b ( (a:) . (c:) )
```

i.e.<sup>1</sup>

```
f   = flip ((.) . const) . (. (:)) . (.) . (:)
```

Pick you poison. :)

<sup>1</sup>*for some reason, lambdabot produces the wrong `const const` here (with the wrong, general signature). I tricked it by running `@pl \a b c -> const const b ( (a:) . (c:) )` which produced `flip ((.) . const const) . (. (:)) . (.) . (:)`.*